# Uploaded file via POST doesn't exist with $_FILES

Tags: php, html, file, post

I'm uploading a form from a HTML page that includes text input and an image file. My PHP doesn't seem to get the file tho, nothing is there. The input field for the photo has the attributes *type="file"* and *name="photo"*.

I'm trying to create a unique name for the uploaded image:

```
$name = explode('.', $_FILES['photo']['name']);
$uniquePath = $photoDirectoryPath . $username . $name[1];
```

This will concatenate the directory for storing photos, the unique username and the file extension (.jpg etc.)

I then call this:

```
move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'], $uniquePath);
```

But nothing happens!! In fact, the file doesn't seem to exist!

Any ideas?

Comment: Is your HTML form properly set to `multipart/form-data`?

Comment: Bingo. I was missing that. The file exists in the code now that I can access its name. However, I still can't move the file. When I check the folder after the code executes, nothing is there. The folder resides inside /var/www

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the MAX_FILE_SIZE input set before your file input? If not, then add that in there, and if that doesn't fix the problem, check for errors on the file in PHP with `if ($_FILES["photo"]["error"] > 0) { echo $_FILES["photo"]["error"]; }` and if you get an error code, search around to figure out what it means and go from there.

BTW I may have typed that code wrong, so check it before you use it.